# Psalm - how to deal with optional classes

Tags: php, psalm-php

I have a cache factory that will use one of many cache drivers: File, Redis, Memcache, etc.
Because it's either-or, my code can be used both with and without certain PHP extensions.
eg. If you use Redis, you don't need `ext-memcached` installed.
But If I run psalm I get error saying:
`UndefinedClass - foo/bar/CacheFactory.php:99:25 - Class, interface or enum named Memcached does not exist`

Is there a way to tell psalm to ignore classes from not installed extensions?

Comment: But you probably need all of them in dev/CI environments, and it's where Psalm is usually run.